# Calculation between three different tables in databases?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am a beginner in programming.

There are three tables is in database: `tblclients`, `tblinvoices`, `tblinvoicepaymentrecords`.

Now, I want to show Total Due in Client Area, right now there is only Percentage Graph showing.

Here is the Flow:

1. I added a client, it goes in `tblclients` with client id 1.
2. I create invoice of 10000 for Client ID 1, It will Record in `tblinvoices` with the id,total amount and client id in respective columns (id, total and `clientid` ).
3. Now I will record payment for this invoice, the client paid only 7000 - This payment will be recorded in `tblinvoicepaymentrecords` with amount paid and invoice id in respective columns ( `amount` and `invoiceid` ).

Now I want to show the client when they will be login to their customer panel, total Amount Due ( for each Client their own Due ).

I will just include this where I want to show:

[image: Table Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    client.name AS client_name,
    tblinvoices.total_amount AS total_amount,
    tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount_paid AS paid_amount,
    (
        tblinvoices.total_amount - tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount_paid
    ) AS amount_due
FROM
    client
LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON client.id = tblinvoices.client_id
LEFT JOIN tblinvoicepaymentrecords ON tblinvoices.invoice_id = tblinvoicepaymentrecords.invoiceid
```

Here is the result I got:

[image]

As per your table structure, this will be your query:

```
SELECT 
tblclients.userid as client_id, 
    tblclients.company as company_name, 
        tblinvoices.total AS total_amount, 
            tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount AS paid_amount, 
                ( tblinvoices.total - tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount ) AS amount_due 
            FROM 
            tblclients 
            LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.userid = tblinvoices.clientid 
            LEFT JOIN tblinvoicepaymentrecords ON tblinvoices.id = tblinvoicepaymentrecords.invoiceid
```

Comment: @GauravSingh i have created the tables and named it myself.. you please change the name as per your table fields name. . .

Comment: @GauravSingh , to make you understand better i have added my table stucture , please look at my updated answer,. . . and let me know if you stuck anywhere.. and if you are not getting any result using my query , please show me your table structure  .

Comment: Remove the previous link and edit the question and add new ,.

Comment: I have attched the screenshot of table structure,,Please find it in updated question.

Comment: @GauravSingh , i have updated the Answer and added a new Query at last , please check it. and incase you get any error paste it over here.

Comment: Not able to do this, i am using codeigniter framework. Can you Please help me with the complete php code So it can Display Result.

Comment: I have tried below code ( that i posted below ),  but its nothing showing.

Comment: @GauravSingh , i have updated my query in the ans, please check it . and let me know

Comment: Thanks buddy ! its just worked as a  charm,You are genious.